# menu item not responding and a method not responding

Tags: android, menu, android-viewpager

First problem is that the menu items `action_edit` and `action_delete` are not responding when clicked.

Second, when you see the method   `insertPostion(String name)`  is called PageViewAdapter1 constructor however the method does not execute or does not do what is supposed to. please the problems are two but kind of are in the same activity. when the `mViewPager` is not added the menu behaves and responds but when the view pager is added they both do not respond.

```
    public class AddEdit extends AppCompatActivity{

             private ViewPager mViewPager;
             private  PageViewAdapter1  slider;
             private List informatn = new ArrayList<>();
             private int current;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_edit);

       Toolbar tool=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);

        setSupportActionBar(tool);
        Log.d("m","addedit on create instantiated");
       mViewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        slider=new PageViewAdapter1(this);

        if( !slider.equals(null))
            Log.d("m","slider NOT null"+current);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(slider);
        Log.d("m","current inside oncreate"+current);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(current);

        if(mViewPager.isShown())
            Log.d("m","viewpager is shown");

        // load the contact

       // getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACT_LOADER, null, this);

    }



            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater findMenuItems = getMenuInflater();
                findMenuItems.inflate(R.menu.fragment_details_menu, menu);
                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            }


            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_delete:
                        Toast.makeText(AddEdit.this,"delete ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_edit:
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }



    public class PageViewAdapter1 extends PagerAdapter {
        private Context mcontext;
        public String mname=getIntent().getStringExtra("contact");

        List informatn = new ArrayList<>();
        private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;


        public PageViewAdapter1(Context context) {
            this.mcontext = context;
           Log.d("m","adapter called");
            Log.d("m","name"+" "+mname);
            informatn=getInfos();
            Collections.sort(informatn,new MyCompName());
            insertPostion(mname);
        }

        @Override

        public int getCount() {


            return informatn.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return (view==(View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            LayoutInflater mInflater=(LayoutInflater) container.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View item_view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.detail,container,false);
            try
            {
            Log.d("m","instantiateItem");

            TextView nameTextView; // displays contact's name
            TextView phoneTextView; // displays contact's phone
            TextView emailTextView; // displays contact's email
            TextView streetTextView; // displays contact's street
            TextView cityTextView; // displays contact's city
            TextView stateTextView; // displays contact's state

            TextView zipTextView; // displays contact's zip

            // get the EditTexts

            nameTextView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView1);
            phoneTextView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.phoneTextView1);
            emailTextView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.emailTextView1);
            streetTextView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.streetTextView1);
            cityTextView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.cityTextView1);
            stateTextView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.stateTextView1);
            zipTextView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.zipTextView1);


            nameTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).name);
            phoneTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).phone);
            streetTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).street);
            emailTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).eamil);
            cityTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).City);
            stateTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).state);
            zipTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).zip);


            container.addView(item_view);
        }
            catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return item_view;


        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((GridLayout)object);
        }

        private ACursorWrapper queryInfo(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs){

            mDatabase = new AddressBookDatabaseHelper(mcontext)
                    .getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
                    DatabaseDescription.Contact.TABLE_NAME,
                    null, // columns - null selects all columns
                    whereClause,
                    whereArgs,
                    null, // groupBy
                    null, // having
                    null // orderBy
            );
            return new ACursorWrapper(cursor);
        }




        public List getInfos() {

            List information = new ArrayList<>();
            ACursorWrapper cursor = queryInfo(null, null);
            try {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    information.add(cursor.getInfo());
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
            return information;
        }


        public Info getInfo(int id) {

            ACursorWrapper cursor = queryInfo(
                    DatabaseDescription.Contact._ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { id+"" }
            );
            try {
                if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getInfo();
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }



    }


    public void insertPostion(String name){


        for(int i=0;i<informatn.size();i++){

            informatn.get(i).current=i;

            Log.d("m","indexes"+i);

        }
        for(int i=0;i<informatn.size();i++){
            Log.d("m","current"+i);
            if(informatn.get(i).name.equals(name)) {
                current = i;

                break;
            }



        }




    }


    class MyCompName implements Comparator { // eclipse ask for casting object
        public int compare(Object emp1, Object emp2) {

            String emp1Name = ((Info) emp1).name;

            String emp2Name = ((Info) emp2).name;

            return emp1Name.compareTo(emp2Name);
            //return (int)((emp2Name*100) - (emp1Name*100.0));
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: why are you passing null here?  ACursorWrapper cursor = queryInfo(null, null);

Comment: Also whenever you post some code please post the formatted code. That shows professionalism

Comment: to select all colmns

Comment: Are you sure it returns all columns? Have you verified it?

Comment: yes please understand that this code has been running and is running except the two problems I asked

Comment: @amanuel It doesn't matter if it was running or not - it should be properly formatted. Nobody is going to read that.

Comment: Your profile is not about android please pick questions you can answer